# How can represent this matrix in HTML code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2d Matrix (mirrored) and it works as I intended. However, I don't know how to code it properly JavaScript so it doesn't create additional div elements. In the matrix I have the (x,y) index so it changes the right position. However, when it comes to render it on screen it appends(adds) new .

```
createBoard() {
    let specialSquares = {
      '3xW': [0, 7, 105],
      '3xL': [20, 76, 80],
      '2xW': [16, 32, 48, 64],
      '2xL': [3, 36, 45, 52, 92, 96, 108],
      'CT': [112]
    };
    this.board = [...new Array(15)].map(x => new Array(15));
    let boardSide = 14;
    for (let i = 0; i <= boardSide / 2; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= boardSide / 2; j++) {
        let num = indexOfTile(i, j)
        for (let ss in specialSquares) {
          let idx = specialSquares[ss].indexOf(num)
          if (idx >= 0) {
            this.board[i][j] = ss;
            break;
          }else
            this.board[i][j] = "_";
        }}}
```

the render parts is like this, basically the same.:

```
let specialSquares = {
      '3xW': [0, 7, 105],
      '3xL': [20, 76, 80],
      '2xW': [16, 32, 48, 64],
      '2xL': [3, 36, 45, 52, 92, 96, 108],
      'CS': [112]
    };
    let boardSide = 14;
    $('.board').remove();
    let $board = $('<div class="board"/>').appendTo('body');
    for (let i = 0; i <= boardSide / 2; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= boardSide / 2; j++) {
        let num = indexOfTile(i, j)
        for (let ss in specialSquares) {
          let idx = specialSquares[ss].indexOf(num)
          if (idx >= 0) {
            $board.append('<div/>' + ss)
            break;
          }
          else {
            $board.append('<div /> ')
          }
```

But every time (idx<0) it will append a new div. This doesn't happen in the array on the console because I have the exact position (i,j).

Thank you for considering my request :)

edit: inside indexOfTile function

```
function indexOfTile(row, col) {
  var side = 15;
  if (row < side && row >= 0 && col < side && col >= 0) {
    return row * side + col;
  }
```

[image: Board and matrix in console]

Comment: ```$board.append(`<div>${ss}</div>`)```?

Comment: what is `indexOfTile()`?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ.  I edited the post so you can see the function. It gives the index of the square of the board from 0 to 244.
  }

Comment: I think you are approaching from the wrong side to the problem. Why don't you just create an empty board, and only fill the special squares?

Comment: The code you've provided in your question has syntax errors. Could you please provide syntactically acceptable code? Try creating a minimal reproducible example in JSFiddle or right here in the code snippets. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ЕлинЙ.

I'm definitely over complicating myself ... But I don't know how to do it. The board is just div's without an index , I don't know how to reach them without going 1 by 1. that is why I made the matrix. I thought if i could make it work on the console I could transfer that to to screen(html)...

Comment: Can you change the board, to have some classes? Or it is something that you cannot change, like coming from a third party source?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ.
we are suppose to create the classes for all. (board, squares, tiles , players , etc). someone is making the classes. for now  I am in charge of the matrix and layout of the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an empty board and never re-create it again. Just give each tile specific classes or ids with their coordinates like `<div id='tile-0-7', class='tile'></div>`. Then instead of removing and re-creating the whole board, just empty the contents and fill the necessary ones using something like:

```js
let specialSquares = {
  '3xW': [0, 7, 105],
  '3xL': [20, 76, 80],
  '2xW': [16, 32, 48, 64],
  '2xL': [3, 36, 45, 52, 92, 96, 108],
  'CS': [112],
};
let boardSide = 15;

$('.tile').html('_');
Object.keys(specialSquares).forEach(squareName => {
  let tiles = specialSquares[squareName];
  tiles.forEach(tile => {
    let x = Math.floor(tile / boardSide);
    let y = tile % boardSide;
    $(`#tile-${x}-${y}`).html(squareName);
  })
})
```

To create the matrix, I'd go like:

```js
function createBoard() {
  let specialSquares = {
    '3xW': [0, 7, 105],
    '3xL': [20, 76, 80],
    '2xW': [16, 32, 48, 64],
    '2xL': [3, 36, 45, 52, 92, 96, 108],
    'CT': [112],
  };
  let boardSide = 15;
  this.board = Array(boardSide).fill(0).map(() => Array(boardSide).fill('_'));
  Object.keys(specialSquares).forEach(squareName => {
    let tiles = specialSquares[squareName];
    tiles.forEach(tile => {
      let x = Math.floor(tile / boardSide);
      let y = tile % boardSide;
      this.board[x][y] = squareName;
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: `tiles.forEach(tile => {
    let x = Math.floor(tile / boardSide);
    let y = tile % boardSide;
    $(`#tile-${x}-${y}`).html(squareName);
`
this is beautiful. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I took some liberties and rearranged your `specialSquares` for easier access from w/in the loop.  Take a look at this:

```
let buildBoard = () => {
   let height = 14;
   let width = 14;
   let board_container = $("#board_container");
   let counter = 0;
   for (let i=0; i < height; i++) {
      if ($(board_container).html()) {
         $(board_container).html($(board_container).html()+"<br>");
      }
      for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
         //console.log(i, j);
         let boardValue = specialSquares[counter];
         if (boardValue) {
             $(board_container).append(`<div id='cell_${counter}' class='non_blank'>${boardValue}</div>`);
         } else {
           $(board_container).append(`<div id='cell_${counter}'>${counter}</div>`);
         }
         counter++;
      }
   }

}

let specialSquares = {
   0: '3xW',7: '3xW',105: '3xW',
   20: '3xL',76: '3xL',80: '3xL',
   16: '2xW',32: '2xW',48: '2xW',64: '2xW',
   3: '2xL', 36: '2xL', 45: '2xL', 52: '2xL', 92: '2xL', 96: '2xL', 108: '2xL',
   112: 'CS'
}

buildBoard();
```

There's a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dbrc12vt/3/

You didn't provide your CSS, so the format isn't pretty. But insert your own as you see fit.

Also, note that each cell has an ID that corresponds to its index, e.g., `cell_112`.  You can now use those as reference for subsequent selector operations.

Comment: Sure thing, @Mauro. Please mark an answer accepted once you've solved your problem.